# Syntax error sqlite inner join

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax-error, inner-join

this is my code in database solution

```
public HashMap<String, String> getBookTheme(){

    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT title, filepath FROM " + 
                BooksDBHelper.TABLE_BOOK + " INNER JOIN" + BooksDBHelper.TABLE_THEME +
                " ON " + BooksDBHelper.TABLE_BOOK + " . " + 
                BooksDBHelper.KEY_BOK_ID + " = " + BooksDBHelper.TABLE_THEME + 
                " . " + BooksDBHelper.KEY_BOK_ID, null);
    cursor.moveToLast();
    if(cursor.getCount() != 0){
        do{

            hm.put("title", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BooksDBHelper.KEY_TITLE)));
            hm.put("Theme", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BooksDBHelper.KEY_fILEPATH)));

        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }

    return hm;

}
```

and this is my logcat error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ON": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT title, filepath FROM books INNER JOINtheme ON books . bookID = theme . bookID WHERE bookID != ?
```

please check it and tell me a collect syntax .thank for watching :))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no space (" ") between JOIN and table 1 name. And extra space between table name and . column names

Change that to:

```
SELECT title, filepath FROM books INNER JOIN theme ON books.bookID = theme.bookID WHERE bookID != ?
```

And I think you will be fine.

Hope this helps.